# How can I create 2 equal height columns with the right column inside the left column?

Tags: html, css

How can I create two equal height columns with the right column inside the left column? I already know other ways to make 2 equal height columns, however, CSS has no parent selector, so it won't work.

What I am trying to do is create expandable divs. When I collapse the div(s) on the left column, I need the right column to hide. I previously had this working in JavaScript, however, now I am looking for a pure CSS solution. If I can place the right column inside the left column, I can solve the problem. Also, absolute possition will not suffice.

Also, the height of both columns, should be equal to the content of the largest column.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-column">
        ssss
        dddd<br/>
        ffff<br/>
        ddd
        <div class="right-column">
            fffff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container
{
    height:100%;
}

.left-column
{
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%;
}

.right-column
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmVYma

Comment: do you have a codepen with the working version in javascript? It'd be nice to understand more what result you're looking for

Comment: No, but, I can make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FlexBox! (`display:flex;`)

```css
.container {
  height:100px;
}

.left-column {
  display:flex;
  background-color:blue;
}

.right-column {
  background-color:red;
  width:50%;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    ssss
    dddd<br/>
    ffff<br/>
    ddd
    <div class="right-column">
      fffff
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/krabbypattified/pen/ZKxYJW

[Here's a guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the great things you can do with it!

Comment: That is perfect. Now I will only need to use the JavaScript solution, for browsers that don't support FlexBox, and if they have JavaScript disabled, then it will simply display fully expanded. Thank you very much for your help.